# GCP VM has firewall to allow /24 but some IPs get rejected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, firewall

**Problem Description**
Our SRE had setup a firewall for a pool of VMs to allow 10.0.0.0/24 on certain ports.

When I connect through VPN, I get assigned 10.20.10.1 and I can access the target.
When a coworker connects through VPN, he gets assigned 10.20.1.3 on one machine and 10.20.1.4 on another. He can access target on from computer with 10.20.1.3 but he gets forbidden 403 error from 10.20.1.4.

At one time I hadd added a rule to allow all IPs and all ports and yet it didn't work, now ofcourse I have removed that.

**Current Setup**

1. External IP Addresses on VPC Network has a static premium forwarding rule defined for target URL
2. Forwarding rule is assigned to a target pool on load balancing
3. Target pool has 3 VMs, the VM I am interested has label goog-gke-node, Network interface has it's own primary internal IP, alias range of 10.4.0.0/24 and external IP which is different from forwarding. Ingress Analysis shows 10.0.0.0/24 open

Comment: The traffic from `10.20.1.4` is not being blocked by the Google Firewall. Error 403 is an HTTP response, therefore the traffic got thru. You have a webserver/application `permission denied` type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

The RFC7231 mentioned that the 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3).

So the firewall rules set up inside GCP are working fine becuase is allowing the connection to your VM but the IP 10.20.1.4 it seems has a kind of restriction to access so, I suggest to check the application's permissions. I hope this [link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-403-forbidden-error-and-how-to-fix-it) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks John & Rocky. I agree, the server is letting the IP through. But I am not sure where to check in my app. There are two URLs that point to two containerized apps on pooled VMs.
Should I check container settings or app? If both apps are not accessible, I am thinking it's more of webserver config issue than app?